# Permission Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple code that simply opens a directory with this code

```
openFile = open('FileName', 'r+')
```

I've made sure i have permissions to read and write to this directory but i keep getting the error `Permission Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied:`

Comment: ie. `open()` is only for use on files, not directories.

Comment: you can instead make use of [`import os`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#files-and-directories)

Comment: as R Nar pointed out. open is for opening files not directories. Refer to this post on how to read files inside folder. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18262324/3027854