# How to load multiple text files from a folder into a python list variable

Tags: python, file-io, glob, pathlib

I have a folder full of text documents, the text of which needs to be loaded into a single list variable.

Each index of the list, should be the full text of each document.

So far I have this code, but it is not working as well.

```
dir = os.path.join(current_working_directory, 'FolderName')
file_list = glob.glob(dir + '/*.txt')
corpus = [] #-->my list variable
for file_path in file_list:
    text_file = open(file_path, 'r')
    corpus.append(text_file.readlines()) 
    text_file.close()
```

Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:** Replaced the csv reading function (`read_csv`) with text reading function (`readlines()`).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need to `read()` each file in and append it to your `corpus` list as follows:

```
import glob
import os

file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "FolderName", "*.txt"))

corpus = []

for file_path in file_list:
    with open(file_path) as f_input:
        corpus.append(f_input.read())

print(corpus)
```

Each list entry would then be the entire contents of each text file. Note, using `readlines()` would give you a list of lines for each file rather than the raw text.

#### With a list-comprehension

```py
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "FolderName", "*.txt"))

corpus = [open(file).read() for file in file_list]
```

This approach though might end up with more resource usage as there is no `with` section to automatically close each file.

Comment: If you define a function eg. `def get_file_text()` that uses a with section, you can then use that in your list comprehension so that the files are still closed.

Comment: Indeed you correct, I was though trying to emphasis why a one line approach might have disadvantages

Answer (score 3):

- Solve this with the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module, which treats paths as objects with methods.
- Use `Path()` to create a `pathlib` object of the path (or use [`.cwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.cwd)), and use [`.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) (or [`.rglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob)) to find the files matching the specific pattern.

  - `files = (Path().cwd() / 'FolderName').glob('*.txt')`

    - `/` is used to add folders (extend) to a `pathlib` object.
  - Alternatives:

    - `files = Path('./FolderName').glob('*.txt')`
    - `files = Path('e:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/t-files/').glob('*.txt')`
- [`Path.read_text()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text) can be used to read the text into a `list`, without using [`.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open). **The file is opened and then closed.**

  - `text = [f.read_text() for f in files]`
  - Alternatives:

    - `text = [f.open().read() for f in files]`
    - `text = [f.open().readlines() for f in files]` - creates a `list` of `lists` of text.

```py
from pathlib import Path

# get the files
files = (Path().cwd() / 'FolderName').glob('*.txt')

# write the text from each file into a list with a list comprehension - the file is opened and closed
text = [f.read_text() for f in files]
```

### `for-loop` Alternative

#### Option 1

```py
files = Path('./FolderName').glob('*.txt')

text = list()

for file in files:
    text.append(file.read_text())  # the file is opened and closed
```

#### Option 2

- [`Path.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open) with `.read()` can be used to open, and read the file text into a list, and close the file.

```py
files = Path('./FolderName').glob('*.txt')

text = list()

for file in files:
    with file.open() as f:
        text.append(f.read())
```

- Also see [SO: How to open every file in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18262293/7758804)

Answer (score -1):

I find this to be an easier way:

```
    import glob


    corpus = []

    file_list = glob.glob("Foldername/*.txt")
    for file_path in file_list:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file_input:
           corpus.append(file_input.read())
    print (corpus)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import os
import shutil
import csv
import sys

csv_file = "card.csv"

with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i == 0:
            print(i)
            pass    # Skip header row
        else:
            filename,filepath,x,y,w,h = row

            file2 = filename + ".txt"    
            file1 = open(file2,"a")#append mode 
            file1.write("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (x, y, w,h)) 
            file1.close()
```

Comment: Add some eplanation to your answer