# Open and read multiple xml files from the folder

Tags: python, operating-system, glob

> the below holder have 100+ XML files. I have to open and read all those files.
>
> F:\Process\Process_files\xmls
>
> So far, I did the below code to open single XML file from the folder. What I need to change to open/read all the XML files from the folder.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import pandas as pd

infile = open("F:\\Process\\Process_files\\xmls\\ABC123.xml","r")
contents = infile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents,'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) and the `os` module to iterate over every file in a given `path` with a given file extension:

```
import glob
import os

path = "F:/Process/Process_files/xmls/"

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xml")):
    with open(filename) as open_file:
        content = open_file.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
```

**Tip:** Use the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement so the file gets automatically closed at the end.

**Source:** [Open Every File In A Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262293/how-to-open-every-file-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 0):

So you need to iterate over files in the folder? You can try something like this:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        contents = fp.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')
```