# Looping through folder of JSON files to extract the same keyword from each in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the Python code below in which I am attempting to access a folder called downloaded that contains multiple JSON object files.

Within each JSON there is a value `keyword` for which I need to extract and add to the list named `keywordList`

I've attempted by adding the filenames to `fileList` (which works ok), but I cannot seem to loop through the `fileList` and extract the `keyword` connected.

Amy help much appreciated, thanks!

```
import os

os.chdir('/Users/Me/Api/downloaded')

fileList = []
keywordList = []

for filenames in os.walk('/Users/Me/Api/downloaded'):
    fileList.append(filenames)

for file in filenames:
    with open(file, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as currentFile:
        keywordList.append(currentFile['keyword'])

print(keywordList)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question mentioned JSON. So I have addressed that.
Let me know if this helps.

```
import json
import os
import glob
import pprint
keywordList = []
path = '/Users/Me/Api/downloaded'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.json')): #only process .JSON files in folder.      
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as currentFile:
        data=currentFile.read().replace('\n', '')
        keyword = json.loads(data)["keytolookup"]
        if keyword not in keywordList:
            keywordList.append(keyword)
pprint(keywordList)
```

**EDIT note**: Updated answer changing for loop from original response of:
 `for filename in os.listdir(path)`
OP mentioned glob version worked better. Had given that as alternative too.

Comment: Thanks @JGFMK this works, but I had to use the addition of the code you wrote for 'or to only process JSON files:'

Without this addition, I was getting a file not found error for all of the JSONS. I'm not sure why this is, if you have any idea then please let me know to help my understanding. Thanks!

Comment: That's interesting - since I cobbled it together from another similar stack overflow question regarding processing all the entries in a directory. I anticipated your folder may contain things that weren't JSON and added the extra bit. Here was the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18262324/495157) I sourced it from. There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory) handy similar thread too

Comment: I will tweak answer to do that then.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the filenames in the fileList array but in the second for loop you are iterating over the filenames instead of the fileList.
import os

```
os.chdir('/Users/Me/Api/downloaded')

fileList = []
keywordList = []

for filenames in os.walk('/Users/Me/Api/downloaded'):
    fileList.append(filenames)

for file in fileList:
    with open(file, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as currentFile:
        keywordList.append(currentFile['keyword'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`open()` returns a filehandle to the open file. You still need to loop over the contents of the file. By default, the contents are split by line-end (\n). After that, you have to match the keyword to the line.

Replace the second for loop with:

```
for file in filenames:
    with open(file, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as currentFile:
        for line in currentFile:
            if 'keyword' in line:
                keywordList.append('keyword')
```

Also, have a look at the [Python JSON module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html). Recursive iteration over json/dicts is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028979/recursive-iteration-through-nested-json-for-specific-key-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the line `for file in filenames:` be `for file in fileList:`?

Also I think this is the correct way to use `os.walk()`

```py
import os

fileList = []
keywordList = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users/Me/Api/downloaded', topdown=False):
   for name in files:
      fileList.append(os.path.join(root, name))

for file in fileList:
    with open(file, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as currentFile:
        keywordList.append(currentFile['keyword'])

print(keywordList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using currentFile like it is a json object, but it is only a file handle. I have added the missing step, the parsing of the file to a json object.

```
import os
import json

os.chdir('/Users/Me/Api/downloaded')

fileList = []
keywordList = []

for filenames in os.walk('/Users/Me/Api/downloaded'):
    fileList.append(filenames)

for file in filenames:
    with open(file, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as currentFile:
        data = json.load(currentFile)  # Parses the file to json object
        keywordList.append(data['keyword'])

print(keywordList)
```