# Deleting lines in multiple csv files in a folder with Python

Tags: python, csv

I want to delete top and bottom lines in multiple csv files in a folder at once. Then delete the second line after that. My code works well with one file but i have 1000s of files to go through and i cannot specify each file name. How can i modify this to make it work?

```
#Remove top and bottom lines from all files 
lines = open('My/local/Drive/*.csv').readlines()
open('My/local/Drive/*.csv', 'w').writelines(lines[2:-4]);

#Remove 2nd line from all files
lines = []
with open('My/local/Drive/*.csv', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open('My/local/Drive/*.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines[:1] + lines[2:]);
```

Comment: Are you working on a unix env?

Comment: Windows environment

Comment: could you specify exactly what are the lines you want to remove/keep?

Comment: I am removing the first two lines before the header, the line after the header and the last four lines in the dataset.

Comment: if it were linux I would have solved it in 1 command line, anyway I have answered ;-)

Answer (score 1):

***>>>TAKE A BACKUP OF YOUR FILES BEFORE RUNNING THIS<<<***

You can use the following code, where you define path following your needs.

```
import glob

path='.'
for filename in glob.iglob(path+'/*.csv'):
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().split("\n")
    f.close()
    if len(lines) >= 7:
      lines = lines[2:-5]
      lines = lines[:1] + lines[2:]
      o = open(filename, 'w')
      for line in lines:
        o.write(line+'\n')
      o.close()
```

**in my target folder (2 csv files):**

```
$ ls *.csv
input1.csv  input2.csv
```

**file1:**

```
to delete1
to delete2
ID;TAG;GROUP
todelete;B00;AB0
niub12617500;B01;AB4
niub16371500;B01;AB3
todelete;B00;AB0
todelete;B00;AB0
todelete;B00;AB0
todelete;B00;AB0
```

**file2:**

```
to delete1
to delete2
ID;TAG;GROUP
todelete;B00;AB0
niub12677500;B00;AB2
niub16377500;B01;AB0
todelete;B00;AB0
todelete;B00;AB0
todelete;B00;AB0
```

After execution:

```
$ cat input1.csv
ID;TAG;GROUP
niub12617500;B01;AB4
niub16371500;B01;AB3
$ cat input2.csv
ID;TAG;GROUP
niub12677500;B00;AB2
niub16377500;B01;AB0
```

Comment: @enufeffizy: if you are satisfied by my answer, can you vote up and accept? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try and list all files in a directory (having a folder with all your *.csv* files is a great option here!).
This will list you ALL files:

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
```

Or you can just list the *.csv* files!

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
```

Having that, you can do whatever you need to delete those files!

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262293/how-to-open-every-file-in-a-folder) out if you need more insight on listing and operating with that!

Dividing your problem in small problems, everything has an easier solution: **how to open every file in a folder**