# Searching through multiple Excel files with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

So I am trying to search through multiple excel files using openpyxl. I've seen ways to do it where you have 3 maybe 4 files, however I am looking to do it with roughly 30 files. The list of files grows daily so I was wondering if there is a command to just use all files in a folder or something of that nature. Luckily each workbook only has one sheet per book

I don't have much as this is one of my first times using python in a long time however what I do have is below

```
>>> import openpyxl
>>> wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
>>> type(wb)
<class 'openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook'>
```

Comment: what is the problem? what does not work currently??

Comment: It's not that its not working its that I need help doing what I described above the code as I do not completely understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try glob glob and loop through each file.

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob('Folder/*.xlsx'):
    print (filename) # instead of print you can use load_workbook.
```

You can take a look at this link :

[How to open every file in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262293/how-to-open-every-file-in-a-folder)