# python open all files ending with .txt in a relative folder

Tags: python, file, path

I need to open and parse all files in a folder, but I have to use a relative path (something like ../../input_files/).

I know that in JavaScript you can use the "path" library to solve this problem.

How can I do it in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about the Absolute path, below line gives you the Absolute path where your script runs.

```py
import os

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # <-- absolute dir to the script is in
```

Now you can merge your relative path to the Absolute path

```py
rel_path = 'relative_path_to_the_txt_dir'
os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)  # <-- absolute dir to the txt is in
```

If you print the above line you'll see the exact path your `txt` files located on.

Here is what you are looking for:-

```py
import glob
import os

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # <-- absolute dir to the script is in
rel_path = 'relative_path_to_the_txt_dir'
txt_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)  # <-- absolute dir to the txt is in

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(txt_dir, '*.txt')):  # filter txt files only
   with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'r') as file:  # open in read-only mode
      # do your stuff
```

Here are few links that you can understand what I did:-

1. [os.path.dirname(path)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)
2. [os.path.join(path, *paths)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)
3. [glob.glob(pathname, *, recursive=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob)

References:-

1. [Open file in a relative location in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7165749/6194097)
2. [How to open every file in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18262293/6194097)

Answer (score 3):

This way you can get a list of files in a path as a list

You can also filter for file types

```
import glob

for file in glob.iglob('../../input_files/**.**',recursive=True):
    print(file)
```

Here you can specify the file type :  `**.**`

for example:  `**.txt`

Output:

../../input_files/name.type

Answer (score 1):

You can use `listdir` from the `os` library, and filter out only the files which has txt as the ending

```
from os import listdir
txts = [x for x in listdir() if x[-3:] == 'txt']
```

Then you can iterate over the lists and do your work on each file.