# how to read multiple txt files and delete the lines that doesnt contain specific word and update the file

Tags: python, txt

I have many txt files with content like this :

```
707.0 126.0 714.0 130.0 706.0 145.0 700.0 141.0 small-vehicle 0
711.0 140.0 718.0 141.0 712.0 157.0 706.0 154.0 small-vehicle 1
917.0 124.0 920.0 117.0 938.0 124.0 933.0 131.0 small-vehicle 0
3540.0 1210.0 3550.0 1215.0 3543.0 1240.0 3534.0 1236.0 large-vehicle 0
3530.0 1204.0 3537.0 1206.0 3529.0 1236.0 3521.0 1230.0 large-vehicle 0
3582.0 1208.0 3594.0 1214.0 3581.0 1243.0 3570.0 1235.0 large-vehicle 0
2936.0 1082.0 2887.0 1197.0 2782.0 1152.0 2835.0 1044.0 plane 0
683.0 4294.0 734.0 4182.0 864.0 4227.0 820.0 4345.0 plane 0
798.0 4027.0 840.0 3915.0 976.0 3966.0 925.0 4082.0 plane 0
925.0 3806.0 1031.0 3742.0 1106.0 3869.0 1011.0 3929.0 plane 0
1620.0 3987.0 1640.0 4107.0 1539.0 4131.0 1509.0 4008.0 plane 0
```

and I want to save lines that contains "plane" in same file and update

Comment: What lines?  I only see a bunch of numbers and some names.  Even if your question was more clear, this isn't a code writing service.  Stack Overflow is a site focused on collecting interesting questions and answers that programmers with at least a little experience will find useful.  The site doesn't exist to teach you rudimentary programming.  What you're asking requires only the most basic level of programming knowledge.  Get a book on Python, or go through one or two of the dozens of Python tutorials on the net.  Come back here when you've got a specific question about your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `.readlines()`

ex:

```
# open file and read the data
# the data will be stored in a list, each line will be an element in the list
txt_file = open("file_name.txt")
data = txt_file.readlines()
txt_file.close()

string_contained_plane = []
for string in data:
    if "plane" in string:
        string_contained_plane.append(string)
```

when the code above is done, `string_contained_plane` should have all the lines you need and you can use `.writelines(string_contained_plane)` to write the data into any file opened.

Comment: how can I open all files in same time like  ..\*.txt  ??

Comment: i dont think there is any function doing that job for you since files may have very different name so you need to open it one by one or using loops.
why you want to open up all files at the same time?

Comment: **@li ExTReM** : Have a look at this answer in relation to opening all files:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66939114/python-open-all-files-ending-with-txt-in-a-relative-folder

Answer (score 0):

The python **find()** method may be useful for you.

But you should at least provide some code so that we can help you better.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp