# How to open all files in a folder in Python?

Tags: python, file, directory

How do I open all files in a folder in python? I need to open all files in a folder, so I can index the files for language processing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import os
os.walk()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example. here is what it does:

1. os.listdir('yourBasebasePath') returns a list  of files in your directory
2. with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'r') is opening the current file as readonly (you will not be able to write inside)

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir('yourBasebasePath'):
   with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'r') as f: 
      # do your stuff
```

[How to open every file in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262293/how-to-open-every-file-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the `pathlib` library https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

you could do something like:

```
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path('<folder to index>')

# get all the files in the folder
files = folder.glob('**/*.csv') # assuming the files are csv

for file in files:
   with open(file, 'r') as f:
       print(f.readlines())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **os.walk** for listing all the files having in your folder.
you can refer [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) documentation

```
import os
folderpath = r'folderpath'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folderpath, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
```