# How to use set of Python codes that worked for 2 files & loop the codes over multiple file in the same directory on python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

I have a set of Python codes that I used to perform a task involving 2 files named **code0001_1234_A2023_12.csv** & **BB_B2024_code0001.csv**. Now I would like to perform the same task for all other files that are present in the same directory, filename pattern and extension (.csv) as two files above. Only difference is the part of file names, which is **code000*_**.

For example,
**code0001_1234_A2023_12.csv** & **BB_B2024_code0001.csv** **code0002_1234_A2023_12.csv** & **BB_B2024_code0002.csv** **code0003_1234_A2023_12.csv** & **BB_B2024_code0003.csv**
the list goes up to
**code0100_1234_A2023_12.csv** & **BB_B2024_code0100.csv**

The code shown below worked for the file combination: **code0001_1234_A2023_12.csv** & **BB_B2024_code0001.csv**. But how to reiterate or loop the same codes over all other file combinations and store each iteration results in separate files.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(code0001_1234_A2023_12.csv)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(BB_B2024_code0001.csv)

print(df1)
print(df2)

d = dict(df2[['structure’, 'barcodes']].values)

df1['barcodes_1']= df1['structure1'].map(d)
df1['barcodes_2']= df1['structure2'].map(d)

print(df1)
```

I tried the glob codes but could not get it worked as I'm very new to python loop

Comment: If you had a way to [get all the files names in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262293/how-to-open-every-file-in-a-folder) would your issue be resolved?

Comment: No, I could not solve the issue. I was able to put in to a folder but I don't know how to combine with my original code and save each outputs.